# I need to look up a value within a table, find the value within in a string and return the first 3 digit zip of the string of zips

Tags: find, match, vlookup

I need to lookup a zip-3 e.g.'825' within a table of grouped zips in a single column

```
787, 733    
790, 791
793, 794, 792
802, 805, 800
806, 807
809, 816, 810, 814, 813, 811
820, 829, 826, 824, 822, 825, 827, 823, 828, 830, 831, 821, 834
837, 836, 833, 838, 834, 832, 835
840, 841, 847, 844, 843, 846, 845, 842
852, 853
857, 851
859, 855
860, 864, 865
```

I then need to be able to return the first value in that string i.e. I need to return '820'

I am working on two separate worksheets one with a list of zip-3's and another with grouped zip-3's so I need to be able to match the leading zip in a string to the individual zip-3 on my first worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
=LEFT(INDEX('another with grouped zip-3''s'!A:A,MATCH("*"&Z1&"*",'another with grouped zip-3''s'!A:A,0)),3)
```